# Excel auto new sheet with column copy and today's date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I want to write a VBA routine that would "daily"

- create a new sheet
- give that new sheet a name of the form *DD.MM.YY* (with leading zeroes),
  based on  today’s date (for example, `25.07.18`)
- copy the values from the A and B columns of my `DataInput` sheet
  into the new sheet.

What do I mean by "daily"? Just if the current time is = or > a specified time of day, then create the sheet, else just ignore.

I don't think it's hard to manage. I tried to combine some formulas to put them together but they give me an error all the time.

I was thinking about something

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReportSheet_Today()
    Dim szTodayDate As String

    szTodayDate = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yy")
    On Error GoTo MakeSheet
    Sheets(szTodayDate).Activate
    If Time < TimeValue("9:00:00") Then
        'MakeSheet:
        Sheets.Add , Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = szTodayDate
        Sheets("DataInput").Select
        Range("A:A").Copy
        Sheets("szTodayDate").Select
        Range("A:A").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End IF
End Sub
```

Comment: So what line is the error on? What is the error message?

Comment: @DavidPostill ignoring the compile error from the commented-out line label, that would be runtime error 9 from attempting to dereference `Sheets("szTodayDate")`, which doesn't exist. OP needs to remove the double quotes that are turning their variable into a string literal.

Comment: As I 'm a newbie into vba, and it's a hobby to me to learn "coding" I can't see trough these variable/string meanings. I knew that something wrong here but I didn't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

> ```
> Sheets("szTodayDate").Select
> ```

`szTodayDate` isn't the name of the sheet; it's a local variable that contains a string representing the sheet's name... but you're using it as a *string literal*, so VBA is trying to dereference a sheet object that's *literally* named "szTodayDate"... and since it can't find it, boom, run-time error 9.

Remove the double quotes:

```
Sheets(szTodayDate).Select
```

Now you're going to be dereferencing a sheet object named after *the value of* the `szTodayDate` string variable, which is likely what you intended.

---

**Next Steps...**

Pull the sheet-creating logic into its own, separate procedure; writing small, specialized procedures that *do one thing and do it well*, will make your life much easier down the line.

You can leverage functions' return values: `Worksheets.Add` returns a reference to the worksheet object that was created - by capturing that reference into a local object variable, you remove the need to `Select` it and then to work off `ActiveSheet`.

You can also provide a *destination* parameter to `Range.Copy`, making the entire *select-copy-select-paste* operation a one-liner.

```
Public Function CreateReportSheet(ByVal reportDate As Date) As Worksheet

    Dim reportSheet As Worksheet
    Set reportSheet = AddNamedWorksheet(ThisWorkbook, Format$(reportDate, "dd.mm.yy"))

    'only needed if the sheet doesn't exist at compile-time.
    'if it *does* exist at compile-time, just set the sheet's (Name) property to "inputSheet".
    'that identifier will then be globally available anywhere in the project.
    'Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
    'Set inputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataInput")

    inputSheet.Range("A:A").Copy reportSheet.Range("A:A")
    Set CreateReportSheet = reportSheet

End Function

Public Function AddNamedWorksheet(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sheetName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = wb.Worksheets.Add
    On Error Resume Next ' naming the sheet will throw if name already exists
        sheet.Name = sheetName
    On Error GoTo 0 ' restore error handling
    Set AddNamedWorksheet = sheet
End Function
```

Comment: I see that you have an End Sub in the 1st phase, but I can't see any "Sub" reference for it so it won't run? .Also how I set to create that sheet if doesn't exist at 1 a clock and ignore before 1. I know it's easy for you but for a very newbie it's like to find something in the ocean.I see what you wrote here and I try to understand. That time = or > is set by the boolean variable to see if the IF state is true or false ? 

That statement I can't understand even if you described.
     'Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
       'Set inputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataInput")

Comment: @SarXes typo, that should have been `End Function` - fixed. I kind of deliberately skipped the timing part.. IMO a macro should do just what you tell it to do; if you need it to run at a specific time, then you should implement that somewhere else and invoke that procedure from there. That way you can always test everything and re-run it at will with various parameters, regardless of the time of the day.

Comment: Implement the macro in the code what u wrote ? Yeah I know u see already when u write the comment but I just look at it as wth ? The macro should be with a Sub function maybe ..

Comment: Look for something like "vba invoking a procedure at a specific time", you'll get plenty of results on [so]; basically you'll want to handle the `Workbook_Open` event (in `ThisWorkbook`), and setup `Application.OnTime` to invoke the procedure at the specified time. I kinda dislike this approach though, because it makes Excel pretend to be some kind of task scheduler, and requires it to be open at that specific time, so overnight Windows Update rebooting your machine will break it. But yes, it's feasible, and doesn't involve any special kind of conditional logic.

Comment: To make it simple I don't want to run it all the time just to check the current time with the set time after the workbook was opened and then create that report sheet automatically. It would eliminate the problem if I would forget or just I bypass for whatever reason. Newbie noob asking how to assign a button for it to make that sheet by creating a button . I mean how the command would look like to assign a macro for it , as now if I want to run it I can't see between the macros already reated.

Comment: You'll want to conditionally trigger the macro by invoking e.g. `CreateReportSheet Date` from the `Workbook_Open` handler in `ThisWorkbook`. You'll need the condition to compare the current time *and* whether the worksheet already exists for the current date, otherwise you'll end up creating the sheet every time the book is opened before 9am... which may or may not be a concern.